# Trusted Certificate fails after upgrade from 4.6.1 to 4.7.2

Tags: f#, certificate, .net-4.6.1, .net-4.7.2

After upgrading a service written in F# from 4.6.1 to 4.7.2 i startet getting a classic SSL/TLS error "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel".

1. TLS 1.2 is enabled on all servers.
2. I verified with Fiddler that the old version and the new version of the application both uses TLS 1.2 as they should and have done for a long time.
3. The requests appears to be identical.
4. The service runs as a Network Service, however i get the same error if i run it as admin.
5. The certificate is selfsigned and placed in Trusted Root Certification Auth.
6. The certificate is only used to internal https between our services.
7. If I add the certificate to Personal certificates in certmgr the error disappears and the service works!

From my view it is as if after upgrading to 4.7.2 the Trusted Ca certificates are "ignored".

Adding the certificate to Personal when its placed in Trusted Certificates is not a solution.

I havent been able to identify the change which somehow must have been introduced in 4.7.2.

What am i missing?

Comment: Can you provide the details on the exception, as well as the code that you have which is failing?  Since this is a self-signed certificate, can you provide more information about how it was generated (bonus points for providing the the public portion of the certificate as  a .CER file)?  Code would tell, but: is this doing mutual auth (both a client cert and a server cert), or just server auth?